# What are direct connectors in Sqoop

Tags: jdbc, mysql-connector, sqoop, sqoop2

As we know Sqoop jobs connect to databases using connectors along with JDBC drivers for a particular databases.But as mentioned in the Sqoop documentation by suplying --direct option performance is enhanced.Could someone explain 'direct' mode import.How it is different from normal connectors that uses JDBC drivers.I have gone through the documentation but not getting a clear understanding.

Also does we have a direct connector for Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

For Teradata, you can use TDCH.

https://profile.teradata.com/sites/all/files/Teradata%20Connector%20for%20Hadoop%20Tutorial%20v1.4.pdf